# Primefaces <p:tooltip> does not disappear after another Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Let's say I have some tooltips in my `<p:dataTable>`.
When I change the page of `dataTable` and while another page laods, I move mouse on any tooltip - it shows up, but after the other page is loaded tooltip never disappears.. I've tried to update this, using `p:ajax`, `p:remoteCommand` but nothing helps, actually this made another `Ajax` request and tooltips also stucked. Only full page reload `F5` works.

Has anyone encountered with such problem?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Consider creating an issue at PrimeFaces issue tracker, they may be able to fix this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a PrimeFaces bug, but you can work around it by hiding tooltips on pagination events via JS.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.val}" var="row" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rows="10" paginator="true">
    <p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="hideTooltips();" />

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText id="text" value="#{row}" />
        <!--
            since p:tooltip is located inside an iterative component (p:dataTable), we can't
            just define a static widgetVar value, because there will be a widget instance for
            each iteration, and each instance must have a unique widgetVar value, so we'll
            use rowIndex to achieve that
        -->
        <p:tooltip widgetVar="textTipVar#{rowIndex}" for="text" value="Tip" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<script>
    function hideTooltips() {
        /*
            we've defined a bunch of widgetVars with a dynamic name, so we'll iterate over
            all widgets on the page and find the ones we need by looking for a known
            widgetVar prefix
        */
        for (var w in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
            if (w.indexOf('textTipVar') === 0) {
                PrimeFaces.widgets[w]._hide();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This uses an undocumented Tooltip widget method `_hide`, keep that in mind when updating to another PrimeFaces version, e.g. the method's name could change. The `PrimeFaces.widgets` object is undocumented too.

---

Update. As russellelbert points out in comments, the method's name is just `hide` since PrimeFaces 7.0 - no underscore.
Also since PrimeFaces 10.0 both `PrimeFaces.widgets` and `Tooltip#hide` are part of documented Client API.

Comment: thanks for help! :) But this does not work properly.. I try to change 'textTipVar' into PF('textTipVar'). Of course added widgetVar to tooltips (copied)

Comment: Why do you try to change it? Is your p:tooltip outside the table? Post your code already.

Comment: Edited to further explain why it's done the way it is; fixed invalid comments in js code.

Comment: Shouldn't this `if (w.indexOf('textTipVar') === 0)` be sth like `if (w.contains('textTipVar'))`? Thanks for help and sorry for being so late :)

Comment: @Rafcik, `w` is a String here. JS String doesn't have a standard `contains` method, it only exists in Firefox 18 - 39: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains. Besides, it's sufficient to check that the widget name starts with `'textTipVar'`, since I know that's how I defined it. I use `indexOf() === 0` instead of  `String.prototype.startsWith`, since the latter is not supported in many browsers still: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: okay i got this `hideTooltips is not defined`
view cannot find such function

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! Had to move script out of <h:form>! :)
Sometimes had to use `widgetVar="imprVar#{rowIndex}:#{user.id}"` because there were same participants in many rows :)

Comment: This is great! I had to remove the underscore from the body of the if statement as such: `PrimeFaces.widgets[w].hide();` (PrimeFaces version 7.0)

Answer (score 7):

Incase anybody else struggles with this, I think I found a solution worth trying.
In my case, I had a tool tip that showed when I hovered over a commandButton but if I clicked it it would run an ajax request and return, update a component and finish but the tooltip would still remain.  This is what I did to fix it.

```
<p:tooltip id="saveDeleteTooltip" globalSelector="[data-tooltip]" position="top" hideEvent="mouseleave click"/>
```

Supply two events for the hideEvent attribute and seems to recognize and use both.  The first is for normal mouseout but the second does fire when I click on my commandButtons it does hide the tooltip like it was supposed to do.

Comment: this works but the problem i am having now is that after the ajax event hovering over the element again does not show the tooltip again

Comment: This is super helpful for me. I was using a global tooltip in a template file and I would like every tooltip to be hidden on a mouseleave and a click event. So adding the `hideEvent="mouseleave click"` as a property on the global `<p:tooltip>` component was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Same success as bradykey. This is really useful to me: the hideevent attribute is added only in a template file, within a global tooltip, and this removes a lot of frustration; Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a bit risky as the PrimeFaces Tooltip widget appends its jQuery namespace, expecting a single event name: `this.cfg.hideEvent = this.cfg.hideEvent ? this.cfg.hideEvent + '.tooltip' : 'mouseleave.tooltip';` - so `mouseleave` in the case of this answer would remain without the namespace, and this could lead to some `mouseleave` Tooltip event handlers not being properly removed when they should be, or even some other `mouseleave` event handlers not belonging to Tooltip being improperly removed.