# p:wizard - tooltip is not hiding when next() is triggered with onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, wizard

I'm triggering Wizard's next() when Enter key is pressed while filling InputText on Tab1. InputText has focus and displays tooltip. After navigating to Tab2 the tooltip is still displayed. What's wrong with my code? How can I get rid of this effect?

[Tab1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2bWp.png)
[Tab2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUaM3.png)

JSF page:

```
<h:form >
<p:panel style="width: 25%;">
<p:wizard flowListener="#{wizardBean.onFlowProcess}" style="text-align: left;"
                      widgetVar="testWizard">

                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
                    <p:inputText id="inputText"
                                 value="#{wizardBean.inputVal}"
                                 title="Hit Enter to submit"
                                 onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) { PF('testWizard').next(); return false;}"/>
                    <p:tooltip for="inputText"/>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Hello."/>
                </p:tab>

            </p:wizard>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;

@Named(value = "wizardBean")
@ViewScoped
public class WizardBean implements Serializable {

private String inputVal;
private boolean skip;

public WizardBean() {
}

public String getInputVal() {
    return inputVal;
}

public void setInputVal(String inputVal) {
    this.inputVal = inputVal;
}

public boolean isSkip() {
    return skip;
}

public void setSkip(boolean skip) {
    this.skip = skip;
}

public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
    if(skip) {
        skip = false;
        return "confirm";
    }
    else {
        return event.getNewStep();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please state your PF version?

Comment: I use Primefaces-5.2 but the same effect is noticed with Primefaces-5.3

Comment: The same effect I can also notice for keyboard's layout. I've tried various scenario for updating componets on Tab 1 - with no success.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, just a small omission in the functionality of the tooltip of components that they do not become hidden if the component becomes hidden (and still has focus). What if you do an blur() on the input in the javascript call, does it disappear then?

Comment: Thanks - I will try. Now, I've tested this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428751/primefaces-ptooltip-does-not-disappear-after-another-ajax-request and it's working for me.