# Primefaces ToolTip Sticks in the page without hiding

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `jsf 1.2` and `primefaces 5.2.5` , I have added tooltips in my `XHTML` page and when I do some operations between some `ajax` listener events the tootip sticks to the page and by scrolling the entire page the sticked tool tip gets replicated. How to autohide the tooltip when the focus of the mouse goes out.

**XHTML**

```
<p:tooltip for="zScoreMaxOn" value="Display Std Dev Z-Score Max Results" trackMouse="true"> 
</p:tooltip>
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: there is an other very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428751/primefaces-ptooltip-does-not-disappear-after-another-ajax-request) and a [bug report](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1014) that could be helpful

Comment: JSF 1.4 has never existed, nor has PrimeFaces 5,0.4 (5.0.4 did). And you failed to create a [mcve] so noone can help.

Comment: i am not using the jar from jsf library , customized jar from the company i work

Comment: So you are effectively asking help with an undocumented homegrown old patched JSF version with a fairly old PrimeFaces version and all you can post is a `<p:tooltip.../>`? I hope you understand it is impossible for us to help with this. 100% impossible.

Comment: i am running it under JSF 2.1 , Primefaces 6.0 , JDK 1.8 and running on Liberty Server ,still the problem exists @Kukeltje

Comment: jsf 2.1 is >5 years old, PrimeFaces 6.0 is over 2 years old. Please try more recent versions first